# How to define a Certificate CN name as Variable

Tags: unix, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to make a generic command which when run should take the value of the CN of the certificate as the hostname where the command is being executed .

Command i used currently is as below

```
openssl req -sha256 -new -key $HOSTNAME.key -out $HOSTNAME.csr -subj 'CN=$HOSTNAME'
```

The value of HOSTNAME is defined in the environment variable. eg localhost

Executing the above command creates a key file with the actual value of the localhost.key, but the CN name reflects as $HOSTNAME where as i want the CN to be real hostname which is the value as mentioned in the environment variable , i.e localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use quotation marks and it's a good idea to use the slash before the field name:

```
openssl req -sha256 -new -key $HOSTNAME.key -out $HOSTNAME.csr -subj "/CN=$HOSTNAME"
```

If you need to concatenate:

```
openssl req -sha256 -new -key $HOSTNAME.key -out $HOSTNAME.csr -subj "/CN=prefix${HOSTNAME}suffix"
```